# How should defendant respond to summons with endorsed complaint in NY (CPLR)

Tags: new-york-state, civil-procedure

If a client is served with a "summons with endorsed complaint" for case filed at NY civil court (dispute less than 25k), where it was effectuated by substitute service, then what are the next steps - especially with regards to timing?

is endorsed complaint similar to just a summons where the plaintiff attorney have the obligation to send a full complaint within 20/30 days, or need to wait till the defendant makes a demand for complaint?

Or is the next step by the defendant to answer the complaint within 30 days?

Comment: The next step to respond should appear on the face of the summons. If your copy is for some reason illegible, you can obtain a copy of the court file from the clerk of court. Do not blow it off or a default judgment will enter against you. Hire a lawyer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

A [summons with an endorsed complaint](http://nahoumlaw.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-summons-and-a-complaint/) is a document that combines a summons and a complaint into a single document, rather than having two separate documents, and is normally used in simple debt collection cases.

The deadline for responding normally appears on [the face of the summons](http://nahoumlaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Summons.png).

> The first issue that an attorney should address is the practical one:
>   when is the answer due? CPLR §320 prescribes the time periods for when
>   a responsive pleading must be served. This is generally 20 or 30 days
>   from completion of service (20 days when service is by personal
>   delivery to the defendant within New York State, 30 days all other
>   times). Service is not always complete when the papers are delivered
>   by the process server. This is especially so when service is
>   effectuated through substituted service (leaving the summons and
>   complaint with someone of suitable age and discretion with follow-up
>   mailing CPLR §308). In such a situation, service is complete ten days
>   after the filing of the proof of service (the summons and complaint
>   together with an affidavit of service is known as “proof of service”)
>   with the court. The time periods for other methods of service are
>   provided for in CPLR Article 3 and, in the interest of brevity, will
>   not be discussed here.

You need to file a timely answer or motion in lieu of an answer by the deadline set forth in the summons. Generally, this is best to have a lawyer handle for you but some of the many considerations involved are set forth [here](http://www.marshalldennehey.com/defense-digest-articles/new-york-practice-responding-complaint) (this is the source of the block quote above). They include, admitting or denying each allegation, asserting affirmative defenses, raising any available objects to jurisdiction, venue or service, making a jury demand, paying a filing fee, and asserting any counterclaims or crossclaims.

If you do not respond by the deadline a default judgment will be entered against you.